# Tkinter 'Frame' object has no attribute 'entry_U'

Tags: python, authentication, tkinter

Currently trying to create a login page using frames in tkinter and getting error 'Frame' object has no attribute 'entry_U'and have no idea how to solve it. I have seen some similar questions but none of the answers seem to be applicable to my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
def Page1():
    f1.pack()
    f2.pack_forget()
    f3.pack_forget()

def Page2():
    f1.pack_forget()
    f2.pack()
    f3.pack_forget()

def Page3():
    f1.pack_forget()
    f2.pack_forget()
    f3.pack()

root.title('Frames')

f1 = tk.Frame(root)
label_1 = tk.Label(f1, text='Login')
label_1.pack()

label_U = tk.Label(f1, text="Username")
label_U.pack()
entry_U = tk.Entry(f1)
entry_U.pack()

label_P = tk.Label(f1, text="Password")
label_P.pack()
entry_P = tk.Entry(f1, show="*")
entry_P.pack()

checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(f1, text="Keep me logged in")
checkbox.pack()
#error here
username = f1.entry_U.get()
password = f1.entry_P.get()

if username == "user1" and password == "password":
    userid == True
else:
    userid == False

if userid == True:
    logbtn = tk.Button(f1, text="Login", command = Page2)
    logbtn.pack()
else:                   
    tk.messagebox.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username or password")


but_quit = tk.Button(f1, text='Quit', command = quit)
but_quit.pack()

f2 = tk.Frame(root)
label_2 = tk.Label(f2, text='Page2')
label_2.pack()
but_3 = tk.Button(f2, text='Go to Page 3', command = Page3)
but_3.pack()
but_quit = tk.Button(f2, text='Quit', command = quit)
but_quit.pack()

f3 = tk.Frame(root)
label_3 = tk.Label(f3, text='Page3')
label_3.pack()
but_1 = tk.Button(f3, text='Go to Page 1', command = Page1)
but_1.pack()
but_quit = tk.Button(f3, text='Quit', command = quit)
but_quit.pack()

f1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I am quite new to programming generally and have no idea if what I'm trying to do is possible but any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even though `entry_U` is a widget whose master is `f1` (a Frame), the name 'entry_U' is simply a global name with no particular relation to the name 'f1'.  Delete the 'f1.' prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Just because entry_U uses f1 as the master widget does not make it an attribute of that widget. Just use the variable name you gave it:

```
username = entry_U.get()
```

You will also need to move your login code into the Page2 function.